# Mimicking a local IP address

Tags: android, tcp, ip, ip-address

everyone.

Let's imagine a situation.

There are two IPs on my Android phone, for both radio devices (mobile network and wifi), IP#1 and IP#2. IP#1 forms a TCP connection from IP#1 to a Foreign IP, but disconnects for an unknown reason. Is it possible to make IP#2 appear as IP#1 in the eyes of the Foreign IP to avoid timeouting the connection?

Packages would go:
IP#2 -> through IP#1 -> Foreign IP

Foreign IP -> IP#1 -> IP#2

While maintaining the same IP address throughout the session.

Answer (score 0):

No, because you wouldn't be able to receive the reply packets. They would be sent to the network that you aren't connected to and would have no way to get to you.